# BuildServiceProvider warning in Startup.cs ConfigureServices after upgrading .Net Core 3.0.0 to 3.1.3

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-3.1

I just downloaded and upgraded a project to .Net Core SDK 3.1.3 from 3.0.0.
I did a build and received a warning saying:

> Startup.cs(149,13): warning ASP0000: Calling 'BuildServiceProvider' from application code results in an additional copy of singleton services being created. Consider alternatives such as dependency injecting services as parameters to 'Configure'.

The code is here:

```
services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<DataContext>().Database.Migrate();
```

and I have a note above the line that says:

> // so that it's added in Azure. Applies any pending migrations to the database context

Which I don't remember adding, as the initial project was a Udemy course and I followed along until I had a working website. So I don't remember if I wrote this or if the Udemy instructor wrote - probably him.

**QUESTION** - what is this and can I remove it and still migrate/update my db correctly?

It's not an error, but a warning so not sure what I should do here?

Any help would be appreciated.

I tried to do a dotnet clean and a dotnet refresh, but that didn't get rid of it.
Interestingly, when I debug, I don't see the warning, it shows "build succeeded, 0 warnings, 0 errors" and the app runs. I'll try to update the db with EF Core and see what happens.

Comment: is that line of code in the `ConfigureServices` method?

Comment: move it outside of startup into your `main`

Comment: yes, it's in ConfigureServices

Comment: One option is to use the suggestion from the warning. Move it into `Configure` and use the injected `IApplicationBuilder app` and do `app.ApplicationServices.GetService<DataContext>().Database.Migrate();`

Comment: what's the difference?

Comment: In `ConfigureServices`, your `ServiceProvider` hasn't been built yet. If you manually build it, it creates a copy. Later on, the framework will build it, which means another copy. When you access it in `Configure`, it has been built by the framework and you can access the singleton.

Comment: ok that makes sense, but why would I only get that warning after upgrading to .Net Core 3.1.3. I don't remember seeing that warning before, unless I overlooked it, but I doubt it..

Comment: I'm now looking at another project and I don't even have this line in the startup.cs file. Maybe this was something from an earlier version of .Net Core that I don't need anymore. Mayne I'll just remove it and see what happens! :)

Comment: net core 3.1 most likely decided to add that warning in. I suspect it has always been a "problem" but with net core 3.1, they decided to surface it.